# How to correctly implement tinyMCE skin fonts with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, tinymce, webpack-dev-server, tinymce-4

I'am trying to use tinyMCE with Webpack. All works fine, but editor doesn't want to load skin fonts. For example, this is what I see

[image]

Console shows the following messages

[image]

But if I open, for example, http://localhost:8080/build/fonts/tinymce.woff, font downloads successfully. Can someone help me? Thank's in advance.

As documentation says, first I define skin loader

```
require.context('file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce!tinymce/skins', true, /.*/)
```

Then import main, theme and modules

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce'
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme'

import 'tinymce/plugins/image'
...
import 'tinymce/plugins/autolink'
```

Finally, init editor in React component

```
...
componentDidMount () {

    tinymce.init({

        selector: 'div.tinymce',
        plugins: 'image media table link paste contextmenu textpattern autolink',
        insert_toolbar: 'quickimage quicktable media codesample',
        selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote',
        paste_data_images: true,
    })
}
...
```

Webpack loaders section

```
    loaders: [

        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
        { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({

            fallback: 'style-loader', 
            use: 'css-loader'
        }) },
        { test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
        { test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]' },
    ]
```